# How to avoid abstract class pattern in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Abstract class looks in Ruby code like an alien from remote planet Java. I'm trying to collect Ruby tricks which can substitute this unwanted pattern.

Let's take  a completely random example:

```
class AbstractRace < Struct.new(:runner_count)
  def go!
    runner_count.times.map do |index|
      Thread.new do
        run(index)
      end
    end.each(&:join)
  end

  def run(index)
    raise 'To be implemented in derivative classes'
  end
end

class RunnerRace < AbstractRace
  def run(index)
    puts "I am runner number #{index}. I am running"
  end
end

class CarRace < AbstractRace
  def run(index)
    puts "I am car number #{index}. I am accelerating"
  end
end

RunnerRace.new(2).go!
CarRace.new(2).go!
```

How to rewrite it? A possible approach would be using a mixin, like this:

```
require 'active_support/concern'

  module Race
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def go!
      participant_count.times.map do |index|
        Thread.new do
          run(index)
        end
      end.each(&:join)
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def configure_race(methods)
        [:participant_count, :run].each do |method_symbol|
          define_method method_symbol, methods[method_symbol]
        end
      end
    end
  end

  class RunnerRace < Struct.new(:runner_count)
    include Race

    configure_race participant_count: ->() { runner_count },
      run: ->(index) { puts "I am runner number #{index}. I am running" }
  end

  class CarRace < Struct.new(:car_count)
    include Race

    configure_race participant_count: -> { car_count },
      run: ->(index) { puts "I am car number #{index}. I am going" }
  end

  RunnerRace.new(2).go!
  CarRace.new(2).go!
```

What other solutions could be? Is there a common idiom for such case?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about refactoring working code, which is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just take advantage of the fact that Ruby is a dynamic language?

```
class Race
  attr_reader :participants

  def initialize(participants)
    @participants = participants
  end

  def go!
    participants.each_with_index.map do |index,participant|
      Thread.new do
        participant.run(index)
      end
    end.each(&:join)
  end
end

class CarEntry
  def run(index) 
    puts "I am car number #{index}. I am going"
  end
end
```

There is no need for anything running in a 'race' to extend a superclass.  All anything in the race must do is be capable of racing i.e having a

```
run(index)
```

method that does something.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby I would tend to think of 'AbstractRace' as more of a role for a class to play.  Roles are best encapsulated in modules (as you've suggested in your first response).

If you are trying to come up with a general ruby solution, however, I would recommend removing the reference to ActiveSupport::Concern.  This module is something that comes from Rails and may not be available in all ruby environments.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with what you have written there and I'm not entirely sure what you are unhappy with.

That being said, this is Ruby and there is no need to define the `run` method on your `AbstractRace` class. If that's what is bothering you, then just don't do it.

The reason you put it there is to show both yourself and other developers who might be working on the code that a `Race` should have a `run` method. It's defining the interface. It definitely is not required though, but it is the "proper" way to make an object oriented class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the point of abstract classes

Languages like Java use abstract classes because they want to:

- Collect common code for derived classes in one place (common base class), and
- Prevent instantiating this common base class, because it is a base class.

If you wanted to achieve the same goals, you could do this by:

- Creating a base class with the common code
- Giving it a private constructor:

```
class AbstractRace
  private:

def initialize
  end
end
```

The other reason people use abstract classes, is the same as interfaces: they want to guarantee that some method exists on a derived class.

Unfortunately, there's no such construction as Ruby; in fact, this is "un-Ruby-like." In Ruby, we rely on "duck typing," which means "if it quacks, it's a duck!" Observe:

```
class Car 
  def drive
    return 'VROOOM!'
  end
end

class Duck
  def quack
    return 'Quack quack!'
  end
end

test_objs = [Car.new, Duck.new]

test_objects.each do |some_obj|
  if some_obj.respond_to?(:quack)
    puts "#{some_obj} is a duck! #{some_obj.quack}"
  else
    puts 'Not a duck, sorry.
  end
end
```

This will output something like `<Duck:0x123456> is a duck! Quack quack!`

This is relying on "duck typing," by checking for the existence of methods before using them. This is the closest idiom in Ruby.